# Testing REST API using POST method on cucumber framework

Tags: java, rest, cucumber-jvm

The below mentioned code is run by entering the request:"http://localhost:8080/LoginCheckREST/restful/login" in the POSTMAN using POST method and passing raw JSON format data in the body as:

```
{
      "username":"xyz.abc"
      "password":"pqrs1234"
}
```

How should I write a cucumber test for this application using eclipse

```
@Path("login")
public class CredencialCheck {
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject checkLogin(JSONObject inputJsonObj) throws JSONException {
    String username = (String) inputJsonObj.get("username");
    String password = (String) inputJsonObj.get("password");
    String status = null;
    if (username.equals("xyz.abc") && password.equals("pqrs1234"))
    {
        status = "Correct Username and Password";
    } else if ((username.equals("xyz.abc")) && (!password.equals("pqrs1234"))) {
        status = "Correct Username and Incorrect Password";
    } else if ((!username.equals("xyz.abc")) && (password.equals("pqrs1234"))) {
        status = "Incorrect Username and Correct Password";
    } else {
        status = "Incorrect Username and Password";
    }
    JSONObject outputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    outputJsonObj.put("Status", status);
    return outputJsonObj;
}
}
```

Comment: I am wondering whether the answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. Please refer the test scenarios in the below github path.

https://github.com/notionquest/cucumber-rest-test/tree/master

1) login.feature  --> has the four scenarios

2) Refer LoginSteps.class - for all JUnit methods

**Steps to test your service :-**

1) Start your server

2) Change the `serviceUrl` variable value in LoginSteps.class to point to your endpoint

3) Clone the above github project

4) Go to the cloned project folder in command prompt

5) mvn test --> execute this command

6) Totally 16 test cases should be executed (4 scenarios and 12 steps)